# How to debug Laravel app when no error info given at all?

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Deployed my Laravel 5.4 app to Heroku and a couple of times I've had the standard "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." exception page with the red banner at the top. Blank white page below that. Nothing in error logs and APP_LOG is set to errorlog and other errors and use of Log::Info() all send to stdout, i.e. Heroku's combined logs and proven to work correctly.

So, just this particular error is generating no info it seems. How to debug this? It's a post to a particular route.

Answer (score 1):

If no logs are being written and the web inspector doesn't give any hints, you can add a `dd` statement in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    dd($exception->getMessage());
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

That should print the error message on the page.